# GetAdaptersInfo get different result in debug and release mode

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, mac-address

I'm trying to get the first mac adress readable in Windows. ( Windows Vista, Windows7, Windows8).

**I use this function :**

```
char* CSoftwareKey::getMAC()
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo;
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);
    char *mac_addr = (char*)malloc(17);

    AdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (AdapterInfo == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo 1 ", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);

    }

    // Make an initial call to GetAdaptersInfo to get the necessary size into the dwBufLen     variable
    if (GetAdaptersInfo(AdapterInfo, &dwBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {

        AdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)malloc(dwBufLen);
        if (AdapterInfo == NULL) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo 2 ", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(AdapterInfo, &dwBufLen) == NO_ERROR) 
    {
        PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;// Contains pointer to current adapter info
        do {

            sprintf_s(mac_addr, 32, "%c%c%c%c%c%c",
                pAdapterInfo->Address[0], pAdapterInfo->Address[1],
                pAdapterInfo->Address[2], pAdapterInfo->Address[3],
                pAdapterInfo->Address[4], pAdapterInfo->Address[5]);
            printf("Address: %s, mac: %s\n", pAdapterInfo->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String, mac_addr);
            free(AdapterInfo);

            return mac_addr;

            printf("\n");
            pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
        } while (pAdapterInfo);
    }
    free(AdapterInfo);
}
```

My mac adress is good in debug, and bad in release mode ! In addition, in debug mode, the mac adress is always different.

I turn off all the optimizations, and results are the same, bad in release modd, and good in debug mode.

Anyone have som ideas ?
I use VS2013 Pro.

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

**EDIT :**

I completely corrected my code using the GetAdapterAdresses instead of GetAdapaterInfos.
Mac adresse appear to be the same in my function, but the return appear to be bad in release mode :

```
#define MACADDR_SIZE (6*3)

char* CSoftwareKey::getMAC()
{
    char * mac_addr = (char*)malloc(MACADDR_SIZE + 1);

    // Declare and initialize variables
    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    int i = 0;
    ULONG flags, outBufLen = 0, family;
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses;
    PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pUnicast;
    PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS pAnycast;
    PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS pMulticast;
    IP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS *pDnServer = NULL;
    IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX *pPrefix = NULL;

    // Set the flags to pass to GetAdaptersAddresses
    flags = GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX;
    // default to unspecified address family (both)
    family = AF_UNSPEC;
    lpMsgBuf = NULL;
    pAddresses = NULL;

    pCurrAddresses = NULL;
    pUnicast = NULL;
    pAnycast = NULL;
    pMulticast = NULL;

    family = AF_INET;

    outBufLen = sizeof (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES);
    pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)malloc(outBufLen);
    if (pAddresses == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed for IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES struct!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Memory allocation for IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES struct is OK!\n");

    // Make an initial call to GetAdaptersAddresses to get the
    // size needed into the outBufLen variable
    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        printf("Not enough buffer! Re-allocating...\n");
        free(pAddresses);
        pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)malloc(outBufLen);
    }
    else
        printf("Buffer allocation is OK!\n");

    if (pAddresses == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed for IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES struct!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Memory allocation for IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES struct is OK!\n");

    // Make a second call to GetAdapters Addresses to get the actual data we want
    printf("Memory allocated for GetAdapterAddresses = %d bytes\n", outBufLen);
    printf("Calling GetAdaptersAddresses function with family = ");
    if (family == AF_INET)
        printf("AF_INET\n");

    dwRetVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

    if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR)
    {
        // If successful, output some information from the data we received
        pCurrAddresses = pAddresses;

        if (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength != 0)
        {
            printf("\tPhysical address: ");
            for (i = 0; i < (int)pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength; i++)
            {
                if (i == (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength - 1))
                    printf("%.2X\n", (int)pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]);
                else
                    printf("%.2X-", (int)pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]);
            }
        }

        sprintf_s(mac_addr, MACADDR_SIZE+1, "%c%c%c%c%c%c",
            pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[0], pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[1],
            pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[2], pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[3],
            pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[4], pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[5]);

        free(pAddresses);

    }   
    return mac_addr;
}
```

Comment: you have a `return` within your `do while`. it must be wrong.

Comment: This code is undefined behavior. You are constantly accessing invalid memory. You should consider getting a firm grasp on C.

Comment: I edited my first post replacing GetAdapterInfos with GetAdapterAdresses. Mac adress appear to be the same but it seem's to bu a retunr error. I use the %c format because it's ordre to generate a unique ID for each pc.

Comment: [`sprintf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx).

Comment: I corrected my EDIT with correction on sprintf_s. Always the same problems.